# tkinter mainloop() not ending the script once it completes

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading, mainloop

For some reason the `mainloop()` is not ending. The final `print` statement never gets triggered but everything else does. Any idea what is causing this or how to resolve it? It happens even without the threading.

```
import time
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import *

def threading():
    t1=Thread(target=checkProgress)
    t1.start()

def checkProgress():
    loading_window.geometry = ("500x500")
    text = "The device is being reset. This will take a minute."
    Label(loading_window, text=text, font=('times', 12)).pack()
    loading_window.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    print("The connection is complete!")

Tk().withdraw()
download_location = askdirectory(title='Find and select the download folder', mustexist=TRUE)

loading_window = Tk()
loading_window.after(200, threading())
loading_window.mainloop()

print("Finished")
```

Comment: FWIW, `loading_window.after(200, threading())` _immeidately_ calls `threading` instead of waiting 200ms. For the delay to work it needs to be `loading_window.after(200, threading)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried both, but it doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: It would save time to evaluate your code if you would show your imports

Comment: @JimRobinson My mistake. I added them now. Also, I have messed with many options and this keeps heppening to me. I removed the ".after" completely and ran the thread directly with the same issue. mainloop() wont stop running for some reason.

Comment: The main issue is that I do not know how to end a mainloop when no button is used for this. I basically need to end the mainloop() when the timer finishes. All the docs show how to do it with a button but not with a timer and it needs to be done with threading.

Comment: It is because you have two instances of `Tk()` and one of them is hidden, so you cannot destroy it manually.  Therefore the `mainloop()` will not terminate.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you. I think this is the obvious answer but it does not help unserstand where or how this is happening, or how to resolve it.

Comment: It is so obviously *where or how this is happening*.  And *"How to resolve it"* - use only one instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: Yes but where would this be happening? I posted the code above. There is only one instance of Tk() right?

Comment: No, there are two instances: `Tk().withdraw()` (the hidden instance) and `loading_window = Tk()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Would you mind posting a solution. askDirectory opens 2 windows and all docs say to use withdraw to hide the unnecessary one. How should I resolve this? I think you have the answer to this issue I just cannot see exactly how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are two instances of `Tk()`:

- `Tk().withdraw()` (hidden instance)
- `loading_window = Tk()`

Even you close the second instance, `mainloop()` will still be running because there is a hidden instance of `Tk()`.

You should use only one instance of `Tk()` instead:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import *

def threading():
    t1=Thread(target=checkProgress)
    t1.start()

def checkProgress():
    loading_window.geometry("500x500")
    text = "The device is being reset. This will take a minute."
    Label(loading_window, text=text, font=('times', 12)).pack()
    loading_window.update()
    loading_window.deiconify()  # show the window
    time.sleep(3)
    print("The connection is complete!")
    loading_window.destroy()  # destroy the window

# only create one instance of Tk()
loading_window = Tk()
loading_window.withdraw() # hide the window
download_location = askdirectory(title='Find and select the download folder', mustexist=TRUE)
loading_window.after(200, threading)
loading_window.mainloop()

print("Finished")
```

---

Note that most people said it is not recommended to update tkinter widgets directly in a child thread because tkinter is not thread safe.

Below is the modified code to minimize direct update tkinter widgets in a thread:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import *

def threading():
    loading_window.deiconify()  # show the window
    t1=Thread(target=checkProgress)
    t1.start()

def checkProgress():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("The connection is complete!")
    loading_window.after(10, loading_window.destroy)  # destroy the window


loading_window = Tk()
loading_window.geometry("500x500")
text = "The device is being reset. This will take a minute."
Label(loading_window, text=text, font=('times', 12)).pack()

loading_window.withdraw() # hide the window
download_location = askdirectory(title='Find and select the download folder', mustexist=TRUE)

loading_window.after(200, threading)
loading_window.mainloop()

print("Finished")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The problem is resolved. Thank you very much. I think I spent all afternoon on this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need something to destroy the window in order to exit the mainloop.
You could add a button to close the window, or as shown below add a line to destroy  the window when you are finished:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import time   
from threading import Thread        

def threading():
    t1=Thread(target=checkProgress)
    t1.start()

def checkProgress():
    loading_window.geometry = ("500x500")
    text = "The device is being reset. This will take a minute."
    tk.Label(loading_window, text=text, font=('times', 12)).pack()
    loading_window.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    # destroy the window
    loading_window.destroy()
    print("The connection is complete!")

if __name__=="__main__" :
    # tk().withdraw()
    download_location = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Find and select the download folder', mustexist=tk.TRUE)
    
    loading_window = tk.Tk()
    loading_window.after(200, threading)
    loading_window.mainloop()
    
    print("Finished")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but this doesn't work. The script is still running once complete.

Comment: BTW, this is how I had it originally. The destroy does destroy the window but the script is still running in the background. If I use a button, it kills the script, or if I don't use threading, it kills the script. Maybe I have to use a button for this?

Comment: No, nothing is running on my machine after the set() event.

Comment: @Hermann12 I am not sure why. On my machine the mainloop() still runs with your code. I posted a solution to this. It is extremely annoying I had to use a button.

Comment: @Hermann12 interestingly, if I add the tk.withdraw and the askidir code back to the top, even the button does not close the mainloop anymore. I think I should not have used tkinter at this point. It seems to have a lot of issues maybe.